# Flask login_required cause 401 error when requested

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask backend which its login is handled with LoginManager.

When i want to request my APIs with js, my @login_required APIs cause 401 unauthorized error.

We solved this problem for android app by sending session back to server.
But we dont have any idea to how to solve this issue in front end and javascript.

All APIs work with postman correctly but they dont work when they are requested after login.

Any idea ?

Comment: Please show some code, then it is easier to help.

Comment: I've asked this question with code in this post but there was no answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53584871/request-to-flask-server-returns-401-after-login. @cleb

Comment: @Cleb code is in above link

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem.
but it was because i spell mistake;

take care these code:

```html
login_manager.login_view = "auth.login"
```

Answer (score 0):

File where login Manager is defined:-
[https://github.com/saifraider/FullStackPython/blob/master/project/**init**.py](https://github.com/saifraider/FullStackPython/blob/master/project/__init__.py)

File where login/signup of a user is handled:-
https://github.com/saifraider/FullStackPython/blob/master/project/users/views.py

File where login_required is used:- 
https://github.com/saifraider/FullStackPython/blob/master/project/home/views.py

Also verify, if you have the following code,

`@login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(user_id):
return User.query.filter(User.id == int(user_id)).first()`

Hopefully this helps

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you have any source code or example which implements LoginManager with APIs ?

Answer (score 0):

make sure that in your `/etc/httpd/conf.d/app.conf` you have

```
WSGIPassAuthorization On
```

in order to pass Auth Headers. (https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/master/configuration-directives/WSGIPassAuthorization.html)

Regards,
José